# Asp.WebAPI with Mediatr12 and FluentValidation (migration)

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, clean-architecture, mediatr

I'm creating a *Asp.Net Web Api*, using clean architecture, CQRS, MediatR and FluentValidation. Recently, MediatR was updated to version 12. I'm having troubles doing the migration (from v11 to v12).

Everything works fine using *MediatR v11*. But while using *v12*, the *RequestHandlers *are not automatically detected at run-time.

The exception:

```
No service for type 'MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Application.UseCases.Weather.Queries.GetWeatherQuery,CSharpFunctionalExtensions.Result`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Application.UseCases.Weather.Queries.GetWeatherResponse]]]' has been registered.
```

I created a small repository, using MediatR v11 and v12. Can you help me?

- [v11](https://github.com/santos-an/mediatrv12/tree/mediatr11)
- [v12](https://github.com/santos-an/mediatrv12/tree/main)

I'm using clean architecture, with the usual layers:

- Api layer (app's main entry point)
- Application (commands,queries and query handlers)
- Domain (entities)

## **MediatR v12 project dependencies:**

**Api project:**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="11.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="11.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.DependencyInjectionExtensions" Version="11.5.1" />
    
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR.Extensions.FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="4.0.0" />
    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**Application project:**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CSharpFunctionalExtensions" Version="2.38.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="11.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="12.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

## **MediatR v11 project dependencies:**

**Api project:**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="11.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="11.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.DependencyInjectionExtensions" Version="11.5.1" />
    
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="11.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR.Extensions.FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="11.1.0" />
    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**Application project:**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CSharpFunctionalExtensions" Version="2.38.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="11.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="11.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I'm using the sample code for `WeatherForecastController`.

I follow the [migration guide](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Migration-Guide-11.x-to-12.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `GetWeatherQuery` and its corresponding `GetWeatherQueryHandler` are in your `Application` assembly.

In your `MediatR` v11 version you register that handler in a single call passing in all loaded assemblies, which includes that `Application` assembly.

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
services.AddMediatR(assemblies);
```

---

In your `MediatR` v12 version based code you only register the handlers present in the `Api` assembly.

```
services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly));
```

To also register the ones in the `Application` assembly in a similar way you need to call `RegisterServicesFromAssemblies` passing in the same set of assemblies.

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(assemblies));
```

Alternatively, you can be more explicit and only call `RegisterServicesFromAssembly` on the 2 concerning assemblies containing `MediatR` handlers and so.
This has the benefit of less assembly scanning, since above `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` call returns quite some assemblies.

```
services.AddMediatR(cfg => 
{
    cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly);
    cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(GetWeatherQuery).Assembly);
});
```